# Show that the space $l^2= \{ a \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} | \sum |a_k|^{2} < \infty \}$ is a Banach space

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

If we have

$l^2= \{ a \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} | \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} |a_k|^{2} < \infty \}$ and $||a||_2 = (\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} |a_k|^2 )^{1/2}$

**1**

Proposition: $l^2 $ is a vector space.

We need to show that $\lambda a \in l^2$ and $(a+b)\in l^2$  for $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$  and $a,b\in l^2$ .

for the scalar multiplication: $\lambda a = \sum _{k=0}^{\infty}|\lambda a_k|^2 = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}|\lambda|^2|a_k|^2=|\lambda|^2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}|a_k|^2$

the closure under addition: $a+b = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}|a_{k}+b_{k}|^2\le \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}|a_k|^2 +2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}|a_kb_k|+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}|b_k|^2  $

The first and last term are finite because $a$ and $b$ are taken from $l^2$, but how do I deal with $2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}|a_kb_k|$ ?

**2**

Proposition: $||.||_{2}$ is a norm on $l^2$.

We need to show that from $||x||_2 = 0$ it follows that $x=0$, that $||\lambda x||_2 = |\lambda| ||x||_2$ and $||x+y||_2 \le ||x||_2 + ||y||_2$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x,y \in l^2$.

If $||x||_2 = (\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}|x_k|^2)^{1/2} = 0  $, then $x_k = 0$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$.

For the scalar multiplication: $||\lambda x ||_2 = (\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}|\lambda x_k|^2 )^{1/2} = (|\lambda|^2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}| x_k|^2 )^{1/2} = |\lambda| (\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}| x_k|^2 )^{1/2} = |\lambda| ||x||_2 $.

For the triangular inequality property: $||x+y||_2^2= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}|x_k+y_k|^2 \le \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}|x_{k}|^2 +2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}|x_k y_k|+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}|y_k|^2$.

It is the same as in 1 when showing for closure under addition.... is $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}|x_{k}y_{k}| \le (\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} | x_{k}|^2)^{1/2}(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}|y_{k}|^2)^{1/2}$, how can one show that this inequality is true? If this was proven then:

$||x+y||_2^2= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}|x_k+y_k|^2 \le \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}|x_{k}|^2 +2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}|x_k y_k|+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}|y_k|^2 \le ||x||_2^2+2||x||_2||y||_2 + ||y||_2^2 = (||x||_2+||y||_2)^2$

**3**

Proposition: $(l^2,||.||_2)$ is a Banach space.

We need to show completeness by showing that every Cauchy sequence converges.

If we suppose that we have elements $(a_k)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \in l^2$ that form a Cauchy sequence and an $\epsilon > 0$ then there must be an $N$ such that : $$||a_k - a_m ||_2^2 = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |(a_{k})_n-(a_{m})_n|^2 < \epsilon ^2 $$ with $k,m\ge N $ from this it follows that: $$|(a_{k})_n-(a_{m})_n|< \epsilon,$$
so every subsequence is a Cauchy sequence and has a limit.

Are 1,2, and 3 correct now?

Comment: Your proofs of (1) and (2) are both nonsense.

Comment: Choose a sequence of epsilon so that they added up to a finite number, 1/2^n for example.

Comment: In fact, everything you've written seems to be nonsense, starting with your definition of $l^2$. You should go back to the beginning, writing down carefully what you're doing at each step.

Comment: Be careful that $a$ is a sequence of real numbers $a=(a_1, a_2, a_3,\ldots)$.
Hence your Cauchy sequence $(a_n)\subset l^2$ is a sequence of real sequences $a_n=(a_{n,1},a_{n,2},\ldots,a_{n,k},\ldots)$

Comment: I don't think "proof is wrong" is a legitimate reason to down vote.

Comment: i tried to correct it... is it right now ?

Comment: Your formula $a+b = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}|a_{k}+b_{k}|^2$ is incorrect/meaningless. The expression on the left is an element of $\ell_2$; the expression on the right is a number. Also a proof should not be just a list of formulas; add some text that explains what you are doing.

Comment: You say I should explain better what I am doing, can you give me an example from above what I could have added to show better what I have not understood ? Also, if the expression $a+b = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}|a_{k}+b_{k}|^2$ is meaningless, then how can i show the closure and scalar multiplication?

Comment: You can write something along these lines: To prove that the sum of $a$ and $b$ belongs to $\ell_2$ for every $a,b\in \ell_2$, we show that the series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (a_i + b_i)^2$ converges. <insert your formulas here>

Comment: If the main purpose of your question is to ask for checking and criticism of your proof (as opposed to asking for any proof of the mentioned fact), you should use ([tag:proof-verification]) tag to make this clear.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $a$ and $b$ are in $l^2(\mathbb R)$. You showed that to show that $a+ b$ is also in $l^2(\mathbb R)$, you needed to show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_nb_n|$ is finite. This is a corollary of the famous result, the *Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality*.

**Proposition** *(Cauchy-Schwarz)* For real numbers $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$ and $b_1, b_2,\ldots, b_n$, 
$$ \left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_kb_k \right)^2 \leq \left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2\right) \left(\sum_{k=1}^n b_k^2\right).
$$
The proof is given in most linear algebra texts. A hint to the proof can also be found on MathWorld: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchysInequality.html.